# Trying to dereference/use double pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

So I am having trouble using/dereferencing a double pointer in C. It gives me the error message request for member ***** in something not a structure or union. Now, I saw many post with similar questions but, the solutions like doing `(*head)` and `head = &temp` do not work. Can someone just help me, please?

```
vertex_t **create_graph(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   vertex_t **head, *temp;

   temp = malloc(sizeof(vertex_t));

   head = head->temp;
   head->name = argv[1];

   head->next = malloc(sizeof(vertex_t));
   head->next->name = argv[2];
   head->next->next = 0;

   head->adj_list = malloc(sizeof(adj_vertex_t));
   head->adj_list->edge_weight = atoi(argv[3]);
   head->adj_list->vertex = head->next;

   head->next->adj_list = malloc(sizeof(adj_vertex_t));
   head->next->adj_list->edge_weight = atoi(argv[3]);
   head->adj_list->vertex = head;

   return head;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect the statement `head = head->temp` to do? Why do you even make `head` a double pointer, since you're using it as a single pointer? Why use double pointers here at all?

Comment: I am trying to point the head pointer to temp. I tried head = temp which doesn't work either. I want a double pointer because I am forced to use it in a function that requires a double pointer argument. I don't know how I would use it otherwise.

Comment: You would just pass the address of the head pointer to your other function that wants a pointer reference. You're declaring a pointer to a pointer here but using it as a regular pointer.

Comment: @Jason Coco So how would I use it as a double pointer? That is exactly what I cannot figure out. I tried using (*head) but doesn't work!

Comment: Please do your homework — make it clear to yourself what exactly does `add_edge` do with its arguments and why does it take a `vertex_t**`.

Answer (score 3):

Everything there says you should be using `vertex_t *head`.

Also, `head = head->temp;` is going to crash since you haven't yet assigned `head`.

Comment: I am aware that just *head works. But I need a double pointer to be returned so I can use it in another function with a double pointer argument. Lets say I make it head=temp, that still doesn't work

Comment: What other function needs a double pointer argument? Usually, the only reason you would use a double pointer for a case like this is if you wanted to modify a caller's pointer (an 'out' parameter).

Comment: void add_edge (vertex_t **vtxhead, char *v1_name, char *v2_name, int weight); //This is the function I wanna use. vtxhead will ofcourse be a pointer to the head of typedef *vertex_t

Comment: The other reason is if the function receives an array of pointers to this `vertex_t`.

Comment: *"is going to crash"* - You hope.

Comment: @user1691596: Yeah, see, in `add_edge`, I'd expect the caller to pass in `&head` for some variable `head`, which would be updated by `add_edge` if it had to change the list head. (assuming based on the name of the function). So you only have to return a `vertex_t *` since you're making a brand new `head`.

Comment: Actually that **vtx_head is just so I can point to the beginning of the list, which is a list of vertex_t type. It is a function that I am forced to use as it is part of the assignment

Answer (score -1):

is this meets your requirements ?

```
vertex_t **create_graph(int argc, char *argv[]) {
vertex_t *head, **temp;

head = malloc(sizeof(vertex_t));
temp = malloc(sizeof(vertex_t*));
*temp = head;

head->name = argv[1];

head->next = malloc(sizeof(vertex_t));
head->next->name = argv[2];
head->next->next = 0;

head->adj_list = malloc(sizeof(adj_vertex_t));
head->adj_list->edge_weight = atoi(argv[3]);
head->adj_list->vertex = head->next;

head->next->adj_list = malloc(sizeof(adj_vertex_t));
head->next->adj_list->edge_weight = atoi(argv[3]);
head->adj_list->vertex = head;

 return temp;
}
```

Comment: This sets you up for a memory corruption bug. You are returning a pointer to a local variable that's going to be destroyed as soon as the function returns — -1

Comment: No, you are still returning the address of a local variable.

Comment: if i'd hav returned &temp then ?

Comment: Makes no difference, both variables are on the stack.

Comment: now ? i edited the ans.. check out, is it still addressof local variable ?

Comment: Of course. `&head` is the address of the local variable `head`. You obviously don't understand what you're doing here. Bone up on the difference between the variable as declared in your program, the memory location allocated to hold this variable and the value stored in this memory location.